# UIActivityIndicatorView Misaligned

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, position, xib, uiactivityindicatorview

I have `UIActivityIndicatorView` centered horizontally in a XIB.

[image: XIB]

In iOS 4 (Simulator), the indicator defaults to Large White (the color property being introduced in iOS 5), which is fine. The weird part is that it is also offset.

[image: iOS4]

My initial assumption was that something was wrong with the XIB (or something to that effect). However, in iOS 5 (Simulator, iPhone 4), it works perfectly.

[image: iOS5]

Seeing as how the only thing changed from iOS 4 to iOS 5 regarding `UIActivityIndicatorView`s was the addition of the `color` property, I'm stumped. I'm aware that there's probably nowhere near enough information here to deduce the exact problem. I'm more concerned about where to start debugging, and welcome any suggestions as to what further information I could supply.

**Further Information:**

- The iPad loads the indicator in a reliable position, only changing colors between iOS 4 and iOS 5.
- I have two static origin points (`portPoint = (x, y); landPoint = (w, z);`), that I manually set on rotation. When the app loads, the indicator's origin is (correctly) `portPoint` (which I've verified via NSLog), despite being visually misaligned. When I rotate to landscape, the origin correctly (visually and data-wise) sets to `landPoint`. When I rotate back, the origin correctly (visually and data-wise) sets to `portPoint`, thus resolving the issue.

Comment: Make a clean build and try again. Possibly delete the app from the Simulator. Check your autoresizing masks.

Comment: Clean/Clean Build Folder. Reset all content on sim. AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone. Still no good :(

Comment: Can you upload a minimum viable project? I see you have a Github which could host it.

Comment: AutoresizingNone? All margins should be flexible!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right that w/o seeing your code I can't tell if anything else is going on but centering a view within a superview and maintaining that when the device rotates is fairly simple. Try this:

1. Make sure the `autoResizingMask` of the `UIActivityIndicatorView` is set to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`
2. Position the activity indicator in the center of its superview, either in the XIB file or in `viewDidLoad`
3. Don't change the frame of the activity indicator on rotation, it should stay centered automatically

If the above doesn't fix it, post some code along with the `autoResizingMask` and `contentMode` values for relevant views.

Comment: So, this wasn't 100% my problem. The one part that was missing is that, for whatever reason in iOS 4.3, there were some erroneous rotations on startup that caused a schism to occur between the autoResizing and my explicit placing of the activityIndicatorView.

Comment: This answer was golden and specifically because it was noted to NOT change the frame of the UIActivityIndicator once the autoResizingMask is set. Once I commented out the code for changing the frame during orientation changes, it worked! Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It sure looks like its positioned as if the device were in landscape.  Check to see that you reposition it properly when the view size or orientation changes.

Comment: Check out my updates regarding rotation? There's a weird phenomenon that might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

1/ Your view (activity indicator superview) is bigger than your display (bad autoresizing mask? bad values in xib plist?) or it has bad position inside its superview.

2/ Autoresizing masks are not set correctly. For the activity indicator it should be

```
(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin)
```

To debug this, try to put logging into viewDidAppear. Get the center (CGPoint) of your activity indicator and use UIView methods to convert it to your top view coordinates (e.g.  `[UIView convertPoint:fromView:]`). This position should be the same as the one you see on the screen.

If it's not, there is some bigger problem, possibly connected with animation states.
Otherwise you should be able to find the view which translates your activity indicator to this  weird position. Log the frames of all views in your hierarchy.

Check that you log the information at the right place and you don't change view positions after the logging.